# Regression terminology, predictor vs IV vs?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, terminology

A reviewer has objected to our use of the term "predictor" in a multiple regression analysis using observational data. They argue that because the model is intended to be explanatory and not predictive, we should use some other term. Any suggestions? I'm not keen on, say, "independent variable" because this, at least to me suggests an experimental design with manipulation.

Comment: It's not up to the intention of the analyst whether a coefficient in a regression model can be interpreted as measuring the causal effect of that variable on the outcome or merely the predictive shift . Your last sentence indicates a causal interpretation isn't justified. If so I think predictor is fine (It's always fine. regression at the very least does at least that) but if the reviewer insists, maybe regressor.

Comment: It is OK to use word "predictor" in an "explanatory" study. Explaining is about predicting what has already occured. Does the reviewer mean "forecasting"?

Comment: Explanation is certainly lacking if the model isn't successful at prediction, namely of predicting the outcome conditional on other variables.  The term predictor isn't intended to be restricted to situations where predicting the future or even beyond the dataset is of primary -- or even any -- concern. .

Comment: In some fields (especially economics) IV is more likely to mean _instrumental variable_. For that and other reasons I discourage the abbreviation where I can. (It's perhaps less likely that a reader will take DV to mean _Deo volente_, but that's horrible too. DV saves  a few characters but no syllables over _outcome_ or _response_.

Answer (score 5):

Feature or covariate are the terms that I use. Another that one might use is [explanatory variable](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/explanatory-variable/).